# Verifying Digital Signature on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rsa, digital-signature

I'm using GAE (python) and have to verify a digital signature using a public key (pem format)
I cant use M2Crypto (its not supported on GAE) and neither the following code is working:

```
pubKey = pem

from Crypto import PublicKey
key = PublicKey.RSA.importKey(pubKey)
```

Now, for this code to work we have to have Pycrypto package, which is already there in appengine, still the 'impotkey()' function is giving error
Also, I'm unable to find the class RSAImplementation in Pycrypto package in GAE

EDIT:

OKAY,
After few hours of mind boggling, finally figured out the problem.
The problem is with the version of pycrypto module.
From what I see, GAE supports Pycrypto version 2.0.1, which does not seem to have certain classes and methods, like RSAImplementation and ImportKey()
I updated Pycrypto to 2.4, on my local machine, and there it is able to figure out RSAImplementation and importKey().

Also checked out the changelog for Pycrypto https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/62247ca754657b6ee8370d8fd62c58b8b881f396/ChangeLog
Looks like support for importing public key in pem format is only from version 2.2

Still the basic problem remains..How to verify a digital signature using RSA, on GAE (since GAE is using Pycrypto version 2.0.1)

Comment: On the line:
 key = PublicKey.RSA.importKey(pem) 
I'm getting the following error :
Status: 500 Internal Server Error Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Content-Length: 0

Comment: But the same code is working fine in my local machine, which has pycrypto version 2.4. So is the problem on GAE due to an older version of pycrypto ?

Comment: You should post the callstack of the failure, error 500 means that something want wrong but in order to fix it you need to post more details.

Comment: This is the log which I got on AppEngine:
'module' object has no attribute 'importKey'